# Counting the number of partitions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

> Let $P$ be a set of $7$ different prime numbers and $C$ a set of $28$ different composite numbers each of which is a product of two (not necessarily different) numbers from $P$. The set $C$ is divided into $7$ disjoint four-element subsets such that each of the numbers in one set has a common prime divisor with at least two other numbers in that set. How many such partitions of $C$ are there?

**Book's solution:**

[image]

I get how the subsets must either be $\{a^2,ab,ac,ad\}$ or $\{a^2,ab,ac,bc\}$, but how do we use this to count the number of partitions? I was thinking of proving it using a specific example such as $P = \{2,3,5,7,11,13,17\}$ and then generalizing it is the same thing.

Comment: I guess a start would be to note that each of the seven 4-sets in a partition has exactly one perfect square in it, and there are exactly seven perfect squares, so each perfect square must occur in exaclty on 4-set in each partition. Where to go from there, I'm not sure.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, that's what the solution says.

Comment: Yes, I was indicating a way to make use of what the solution says. You know there's (exactly) one set with $a^2$, one with $b^2$, one with $c^2$, and so on, and you can try to work out how many of the seven 4-sets can be of the ab/ac/ad-type versus how many of the ab/ac/bc-type, and try to go from there. As I mentioned, that's where I run out of puff. But maybe you could tell us what book this is?

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is from the IMO compendium.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted and re-posted but... I posted Gerry's starting point on the prior version, namely that the 7 primes squared are forced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to type up a partial answer with a view to completing it later... possibly with help!

In every partition the seven 4-sets always include one of the elements $a^2, b^2, c^2, d^2, e^2, f^2, g^2$ each; so those can be considered forced.

I'll enumerate first, the first type of 4-set:

Starting with the 2nd element of $a^2$, $a$ is now forced so there are 6 ways of choosing $b$ in $ab$.  There are $5$ was of choosing $c$ in $ac$ and $4$ ways of choosing $d$ in $ad$.

Next we repeat for the $b^2$ set; again there are $6\times 5\times 4$ ways of choosing the free elements.

Continuing for all 7 4-sets gives us a total of $120^7$ solutions using only the first type of 4-set.

Repeating for the 2nd type of 4-set gives us $30^7$ solutions using only the 2nd type of 4-set, since in these 4-sets the 4th element $bc$ is forced as $b$ and $c$ are already chosen.

What remains now, is to enumerate which of the $3600^7$ combinations of these two types of 4-sets are disjoint.  Clearly every combination must satisfy the "one perfect square per set" rule but I'm just scratching my head at the moment over whether this rule will be sufficient to guarantee they are all disjoint.

Comment: You no longer have $6\cdot5\cdot4$ ways in the $b^2$ set, since you may already have used $ab$. This is what makes the problem rather involved and the remark "it is now easy" somewhat mysterious.

Comment: @joriki I know, I am hoping to later calculate which of the sets are disjoint.  Which may not be possible - but at least it is a lead!  In fact I will DEFINITELY have $ab$ elsewhere.

Comment: Ok there's a better way to sum the combinations.  If we sum for both types of 4-sets over each perfect prime, we get $((6\times 5\times4)+(6\times 5))^7 = 150^7$.  This enumeration now only counts sets disjoint in respect of the perfect primes.

Comment: No, you might not have selected $ab$ anywhere else.

Comment: @joriki ah good point. If I am right then that might be the point the author is hinting at, that makes the question "easy"!

Comment: @joriki Ok the 28 composite numbers is the exhaustive set of all products of pairs of the primes in $P$, so my assumption that $ab$ will definitely appear in more than one set is correct. This fact is what makes it "easy".

Comment: I don't understand. I agree with the first part; $C$ is the set of all products of pairs. How does that imply that if you choose elements in each set independently $ab$ will appear in more than one set?

Comment: Because the enumeration I've carried out includes every possible 4-set irrespective of whether elements 2,3 and 4 are disjoint.

Comment: It seems we're talking past each other. I was merely trying to say that if you choose elements independently in each $4$-set, $ab$ can occur any number of times, from $0$ to $7$, in a given combination. If you meant that it occurs elsehwere in *other* combinations, that's certainly true.

Comment: Aren't you overcounting here?  In ${a^2, ab, ac, ad}$, the order of $b,c$ and $d$ doesn't matter.  Hence there are $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ 4-sets of the first type containing $a^2$, and similarly $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ 4-sets of the second type.

Comment: Perhaps one could use the inclusion-exclusion principle to count the number of partitions that have disjoint 4-sets.

Comment: @Shagnik yes maybe you're right. That leaves $7\times 2^2 \times 3^3$ ways of choosing the sets containing $b^2$ to $g^2$.

Comment: There is a geometric way of doing this using a hypercube of bits but I'm not experienced in doing it.